# How to make a Class out of list

Tags: python, list, class

Hi I am new to Python and I am trying to make a class out of a list from a file and I am wondering if it is even possible or is it better to use dictionaries. My class looks like this:

```
class Program:

def __init__(self, name, start_time, end_time, channel):
```

And the list looks like it:

```
['Channel 1', '16.00-17.45 News', '17.45-17.50 Weather', '17.50-17.57 Friends', '17.57-18.00 Coming up', '18.00-18.15 MASH', '18.15-18.40 Thundercats]
```

Is there ant easy way to do it?

Comment: This is very unclear what you try to do. Could you try to explain differently ? You look for the best way to store data that comes fom a file ? And from for list, you create an instance of  `Program` for each value (except the first) ?

Comment: This is like asking how to make a chair out of wood. The design is entirely up to you.

Comment: Yes, i want to create an instance for every value from the list, but I want to include number of the channel in it as well.

Comment: And you don't know how to do that ? You never mentionned that. Can you share what the file look like ? Before your parsing to list

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the approach:

```
data = ['Channel 1', '16.00-17.45 News', '17.45-17.50 Weather', '17.50-17.57 Friends', '17.57-18.00 Coming up', '18.00-18.15 MASH', '18.15-18.40 Thundercats']

class Program:

    def __init__(self, start_time, end_time, name):
        self.start_time = start_time
        self.end_time = end_time
        self.name = name

class Channel:

    def __init__(self, channel_name, program_list):
        self.channel_name = channel_name
        self.program_list = program_list

plist = []

channel1 = Channel(data[0], plist)

for i in range(1, len(data)):
    name = data[i][12:]
    start_time = data[i][0:5]
    end_time = data[i][7:12]
    p = Program(start_time, end_time, name)
    channel1.program_list.append(p)
```